# I am failing to push a git repo when behind a proxy

Tags: git, networking

When i run `git push -u origin master` , i get :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://network.company.net/pathtoproject/projet.git/': 
     Failed :toconnect to  network.company.net port 443: Connection refused
```

I edit the `.git/config` and set the url with https but nothing change.

How to properly create a repository bare and via git push send it to the network company like `//network.company/pathtoproject/project.git/` ?

Comment: Looks like the proxy is refusing to let you connect to that port (443). Can you connect to other hosts that use 443?

Comment: how to connect to other hosts with this ports in order to test that port 443?

Comment: Any HTTPS web page will do. Alternatively, use netcat.

Comment: No i can not with that port.

Comment: Then you have to change the proxy configuration to let it you connect to 443.